# How to copy the entire contents of an Android device incuding empty space

Tags: android, copy

I connected my android device (Galaxy S5) to the computer, and it shows (properties) that there is 2.2GB totalling, free space 7.3GB

is there a way to copy everything including the empty space (like dd..  /dev/sdX) ?

Comment: Your post is off topic.  See the android enthusiasts website

Answer (score 0):

Just use `dd`, where `/dev/sdX` is your android device, and `/home/username/backup.img` is where you want to save the backup:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdX of=/home/username/backup.img bs=64K conv=noerror,sync
```

NOTE: The file has to be a `.img` file.

If you want a progress bar you can add `status=progress` to the end:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb1 bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress
```

To copy the files back, use `dd` again:

```
 sudo dd if=/home/username/backup.img of=/dev/sdX
```

Comment: thanks for replying
the thing is, it's not been shown as a /dev/sdX device, it connected using MTP protocol, and I can't find the right command to copy the entire device (a device who are connected as MTP)